# how to copy a row from excel and paste in tabulator table keeping fields editable?

Tags: javascript, excel, vue.js, tabulator

I am using tabulator library with vue.js where I want to copy a single or multiple rows from excel and paste that in the tabulator table but while doing so, data are getting pasted in only one column.

Below is the data from excel and I want to copy these data and paste to the tabulator table(Note: Tabulator table has 3 columns as well) So while pasting these excel data, these are getting added in one column in the tabulator but I want these copied data should be added to 3 columns. can anyone suggest me what should I do?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<template>
  <div ref="table"></div>
</template>

<script>
import Tabulator from 'tabulator-tables'; //import Tabulator library
import 'tabulator-tables/dist/css/tabulator.min.css';
import moment from 'moment';

export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      tabulator: null, //variable to hold your table
      tableData: [
        
      ], //data for table to display
      columns: [
        {
          title: 'Name',
          field: 'name',
          editor: 'input',
          validator: ['required', 'maxLength:50'],
        },
        {
          title: 'Task',
          field: 'owner',
          editor: 'input',
        },
        {
          title: 'Start Date',
          field: 'start_date',
          sorter: 'date',
          editor: 'input',
          validator: 'required',
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  watch: {
    //update table if data changes
    tableData: {
      handler: function(newData) {
        this.tabulator.replaceData(newData);
      },
      deep: true,
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    //instantiate Tabulator when element is mounted
    this.tabulator = new Tabulator(this.$refs.table, {
      data: this.tableData, //link data to table
      reactiveData: true, //enable data reactivity'
      layout: 'fitColumns',
      columns: this.columns, //define table columns
      selectable: false,
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: please create a JS Fiddle that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to have enabled the clipboard functionality in your table, without this enabled Tabulator will be unable to accept pasted data.

You will need to set the ***clipboard*** option in your table constructor

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    clipboard:"paste", //enable clipboard paste functionality
});
```

For full details see the [Clipboard Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.8/clipboard)

Comment: still, it won't work. As I made all fields editable so when I click on a particular row to paste a copied row from excel they will get pasted into only one column.

Comment: @Dcoder14 have you managed to find a right solution for your needs? I kinda looking for a same stuff for my app.

Answer (score 0):

The in-built paste parser of Tabulator does not support pasting in a cell for the entire table, rather it pastes in that individual cell as per *DOM* functionality.

I managed to resolve the issue with a workaround.
*Works perfectly.*

Considering you have already initiated the table and you have a table on the UI.

Basically, I am interrupting the paste event of the `div` and then adding my own c*ustom paste parser*, **keeping the table cells editable**.

```
// Global function to make all the tables on the page
function makeTabulatorTable(divID, columnList, rowData, clipboardPasteBool) {
    var tableObj = {
        columns: columnList,
        data: rowData,
        layout: "fitColumns",
        rowHeight: 25,
        columnHeaderVertAlign: "middle",
        tooltips: true,
        columnDefaults: {
            tooltip: true,
            headerTooltip: true,
        },
    };

    if (!clipboardPasteBool) {
        // Only copy function for display table
        tableObj.clipboard = "copy";
    }

    // Create table
    var table = new Tabulator("#" + divID, tableObj);

    return table;
}
```

```
// Render preview table
var previewTable = makeTabulatorTable("preview-table", previewTableColumns, [{}], true);
```

```
// Add a custom paste parser to the table, avoid pasting in cells
document.getElementById("preview-table").addEventListener("paste", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Column names to parse
    const columnFields = ["sand", "silt", "clay", "pb", "th33", "th1500"];

    // Custom tabulator paste parser
    // Trim the clipboard data and then split into rows
    let rows = event.clipboardData.getData('Text').trim().split("\n");

    // Transform each row and convert to object
    let clipboardArray = rows.map(row => {
        // Prepend an empty cell for the ID and split by tabs
        let cells = [...row.split("\t")];

        // Convert the array of cells into an object based on the column fields using reduce
        let rowObj = columnFields.reduce((obj, field, index) => {
            obj[field] = cells[index];
            return obj;
        }, {});

        return rowObj;
    });

    // Enable buttons after paste
    enableDisableBtns(false);
    
    // Set data in table
    previewTable.setData(clipboardArray);
});
```

```
// Generate preview table columns
var previewTableColumns = [
    { title: "ID", formatter: "rownum", hozAlign: "center", width: 40 },
    { title: 'Sand <span style="color:teal;">(%)</span>', hozAlign: "end", field: "sand", editor: "number", formatter: floatFormatter },
    { title: 'Silt <span style="color:teal;">(%)</span>', hozAlign: "end", field: "silt", editor: "number", formatter: floatFormatter },
    { title: 'Clay <span style="color:teal;">(%)</span>', hozAlign: "end", field: "clay", editor: "number", formatter: floatFormatter },
    { title: '<i>&rho;<sub>b</sub></i> <span style="color:teal;">(g/cm<sup>3</sup>)</span>', hozAlign: "end", field: "pb", editor: "number", formatter: floatFormatter },
    { title: 'th33', hozAlign: "end", field: "th33", editor: "number", formatter: floatFormatter },
    { title: 'th1500', hozAlign: "end", field: "th1500", editor: "number", formatter: floatFormatter }
];
```

```
<div name='preview-table' id='preview-table'></div>
```